# Passing environment variables to httpd in centos 7

Tags: centos7, centos6, httpd, environment-variables, php7

In my previous **Centos 6.10** server , I have been able to pass some environment variables to httpd by adding to **/etc/sysconfig/httpd**

```
. ~/.envvars
```

.envvars content is

```
export MY_PASSWORD='somepassword'
```

and then in **http.conf**

```
SetEnv MY_PASSWORD ${MY_PASSWORD}
```

and easily accessing the variable in php trough $_SERVER['MY_PASSWORD']
but after upgrading to **Centos 7.7** this stopped working, in the logs I get:

`AH00111: Config variable ${MY_PASSWORD} is not defined`

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by doing two changes : 
in ~/.envvars after I do the export , I added this line to pass the environment variable to systemd:

```
systemctl import-environment MY_PASSWORD
```

and then instead of calling the declaration script in .bash_profile I used **/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions** to ensure the variables are declared before the daemon starts, for some reason the directive **ExecStartPre** didn't work